# Android spinner keeps on adding the same value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have a spinner on my fragment, the data on this spinner is being populated by JSON from my database. The problem I have is that it always repeat the same data on my spinner.

Example:

Basketball
Baseball
Football

Whenever I switch tabs and return this happens to my spinner.

Basketball
Baseball
Football
Basketball
Baseball
Football

Here is my code for retrieving data on my spinner

```
public class Games extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games, container, false);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp1);
 getSpinner();




        return rootView;
}

private void getSpinner(){
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL (Config.URL_SPIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json;


            e_name = new String[JA.length()];
            e_gender = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
            {
                json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
                e_gender[i] =  json.getString("e_gender");
                e_name[i]   =  json.getString("e_name");
            }
            list1.add("All");
            list1.add("NonSports");
            for(int i = 0; i<e_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(e_name[i] + " "+e_gender[i]);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might wanna consider using Retrofit or at least OkHttp in your Android projects. It's much easier and better optimized than using `HttpURLConnection` and parsing json manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your *Arraylist* data.

```
list1.clear();
```

You should put this at start of *getSpinner()* method.

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: @orange It will clear your *arraylist* data which are added. And while you switch the tabs and again calls *getSpinner* method the data will be clear first and then again add that data.So that data would not repeat again and again. Clear ?

Comment: @orange You should put this at start of *getSpinner()* method.

Answer (score 1):

this happens because you are calling getSpinner again and it's populating your list... You can clear your list at the start of the method

```
private void getSpinner()
{
     list1.clear();

    try{
....
}
```

or you can use a boolean

```
private void getSpinner()
{
    try
    {
      ....
      isListPopuplated = true;
    }
}
```

and then check it on create

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games, container, false);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp1);

 if(!isListPopulated)
 {
     getSpinner();
 }




    return rootView;
```